# Ajax success function shows "1" on the top left corner of blank page instead of refreshing the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I am developing a yii2 application. I select data from the Bootstrap modal popup and submit to a controller action where I have an insert query. After I submit the data from modal popupthe data is submitted it shows a white page with "1" on the top left corner of the page instead of only closing the popup and refreshing the div but as I checked in the database data is inserted.

My part of code:
Pop Up call

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modalgroup">+Add</a>
```

Modal pop up code:

```
<?php
 Modal::begin([

'id' => 'modalgroup',
'size' => '',
'header'=>'<h3>Select Groups</h3>']);
 $mymodel = new \app\models\Contact();
 echo $this->render('group', ['mymodel'=>$mymodel]);
 Modal::end();
 ?>
```

popup form

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'select_group']);?>


 <div class="row" style="height: auto;">


<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm field-profile-name">
        <?php

        $wishmodel = new GroupTran();
        $wish=Group::find()->all();
        $options =ArrayHelper::map($wish,'group_id','group_name');
        echo $form->field($model, 'group_id')->checkboxList($options)->label('Select Groups').'<br>';
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton('Select', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();


?>
```

My Js:

```
    $url= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/contact/group';   

    $( "#select_group" ).on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form= $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '{$url}',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function () {
    $(form).trigger("reset");
      $('#modalgroup').modal('hide');   
         $('#groupdiv').load(window.location.href + '#groupdiv');   
    //$("#groupdiv").load(location.href+" #groupdiv>*");   

        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

my controller action

```
public function actionGroup()
{
    $model = new Groups();
    $post= Yii::$app->request->post();          
    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
    foreach(($post['GroupTran']['group_id']) as $data){    
        $wishdata = Groups::find()->where(['group_id'=>$data])->all();
        if(!$wishdata)
        $connection->createCommand()->insert('tbl_groups',['group_id'=>$data])->execute();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please Help

Comment: In your `$( "#select_group" ).on('beforeSubmit', ...`, change the event to `'submit'`. (You are still submitting the form, and the server returns 1 when you do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `on` event for form i.e. `beforeSubmit` is invalid. Try replacing it with `submit`.

Because of this your `form` is submitting.

Replace `$( "#select_group" ).on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {`

To `$( "#select_group" ).on('submit', function(e) {`